# Array of xyzc values , Find out if 3rd column has any rows with c value equal to 1, or not zero

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, neighbours

I have a selection (i.e a neighborhood ) of points

Each point has a XYZC value. Where C is 1 or 0.

If any of the points has a C value of 1 I want to assign the c value of my centre point to be 0.

If all of the points have a C value of 0 I want to assign the c value of my centre point to be 1.

```
    n=np.zeros((1,1))

    for b in range(0,6):
        bb = coordlist[b][4] 
        if bb==1:
            break
        n+=bb

    if n< 1:
        in_cloud[point][4] =1
```

Is this the quickest and best way of doing this? I am going to be doing it for up to 20/30 points in neighborhood.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `coordlist` as a 2-D array:

```
coordlist = np.array(coordlist)
```

and do the comparisons at once:

```
if np.any(coordlist[:,4]==1):
    in_cloud[point][4] = 0
else:
    in_cloud[point][4] = 1
```

but you should also review the `in_cloud` list, it seems you can improve the overall speed of your code by changing everything from `list` to `np.ndarray` and avoiding the Python for loops like in this example.

Answer (score 1):

```
incloud[point][3] = not any(xyzc[3] for xyzc in coordlist)
```

or if you can first do

```
coordlist = numpy.array(coordlist)
```

it'll be faster to do

```
incloud[point][3] = not coordlist[:,3].any()
```

I know you've used `things_to_index[4]`, but the 4th item is at index 3 so it seems like that's a mistake on your side ("C" is the fourth item in "XYZC").

Comment: Thank you ! Going to try this now, I am aware the 4th term is index 3, my incloud does have 5 columns.